# extern undefined reference error when declaring variable

Tags: c++, sdl, extern

I have 2 header files and 1 source file to work with. Respectively: `Utility.h`, `Game.h` and `main.cpp`. I have declared extern variables in `Utility.h` and am trying to define them in `main.cpp`. This gives me an undefined reference error, which I don't understand. I use the variable AFTER I give it a value, so that should be fine?

*Utility.h:*

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <SDL.h>

namespace Utility {
    extern std::string BIN_PATH;
    extern std::string ROOT_PATH;
    extern std::string EXE_PATH;

    // Omitted rest of namespace.
}
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include "Game.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    // Get the necessary paths
    std::string path = SDL_GetBasePath();

    #ifdef _WIN32
        // TODO check if working on different windows systems
        //  exePath = path;
        //  binPath = path.substr(0, path.find_last_of('\\'));
        //  rootPath = binPath.substr(0, binPath.find_last_of('\\'));
    #elif __LINUX__
        Utility::BIN_PATH = path.substr(0, path.find_last_of('/'));
        Utility::ROOT_PATH = Utility::BIN_PATH.substr(0, binPath.find_last_of('/'));
        // TODO check if working on different linux systems
    #endif

    std::cout << "BinPath: " + Utility::BIN_PATH << std::endl;
    std::cout << "RootPath: " + Utility::ROOT_PATH << std::endl;

    // Omitted rest of source.
}
```

I am including `Utility.h` in `Game.h`, and `Game.h` in `main.cpp`. Shouldn't that put the extern definitions above my `main.cpp` source when linking?

Comment: Maybe that "undefined reference error" comes with a more explicit message, or maybe a line number?

Comment: Your variables don't have definitions, only declarations. It's like declaring `void foo(int);` in a header and then trying to call `foo(42)` without defining the function anywhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @melpomene we need a less generic canonical, the one specifically for ODR violations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To simplify (rather complicated) rules a bit, each variable (as well as other entities) must be defined once and only once in the whole program. It can be declared multiple times. It is important to understand what is a declaration and what is a definition.

```
extern std::string var; // in namespace scope
```

Is a declaration of string variable `var`. `var` is not yet defined. You need to define it somewhere else - only once - by using

```
std::string var; // in namespace scope!
```

In your code, you do not define the variable in function `main` - instead, you are assigning the value to it. But the variable needs to be defined.

Comment: Aaah, this explains a lot... So if I read this correctly, I don't even have to use extern and just define the variable as you would normally do. Then include the header and I can use the variable as I like (after giving it a value). And if I really need extern, don't forget to define it.

`std::string var;`
would be enough in the header. Include the header and then define it.
`var = '....';`

Comment: @nepp95, nope, unless you use C++17 `inline` variables. If you defined the variable in the header, you are likely to have other problem - a double definition, if another file includes the same header. If `inline` variables are not for you, you will have to (one of the easiest solutions) create another `.cpp` file and define your variables there.

Comment: @nepp95 As a general rule, don't define variables or functions in headers (the big exception in C++ is templates).

Comment: @melpomene, why? inline functions (and variables recently) are great way to provide header-only libraries, which is often of big benefit.

Comment: @SergeyA Yeah, true. I was assuming that newbies wouldn't reach for inline functions first.

Comment: So then to conclude. The correct way to do this is leaving the extern declaration as it was. Then declaring the variable (preferably) in global scope. Then give it a value and use it as I wish?

Answer (score 1):

The lines

```
Utility::BIN_PATH = path.substr(0, path.find_last_of('/'));
Utility::ROOT_PATH = Utility::BIN_PATH.substr(0, binPath.find_last_of('/'));
```

don't define the variables. They just assign values to them. To define them, use:

```
std::string Utility::BIN_PATH;
std::string Utility::ROOT_PATH;
```

in the global scope. Add similar line for `EXE_PATH`.

```
std::string Utility::EXE_PATH;
```

You can also define them using

```
namespace Utility
{
   std::string BIN_PATH;
   std::string ROOT_PATH;
   std::string EXE_PATH;
}
```

Make sure that those lines appear in a .cpp file, not in a .h file.